# Weird sizes / bounds on Java2d / AWT text rendering with given font pt size and dpi screen resolution?

Tags: java, fonts, size, awt, dpi

I just started rendering texts directly using **Java2D / AWT** on screen. Essentially it works, but I have trouble understanding the pixel sizes / dimensions of the results as reported by AWT and rendered on screen.

Parameters:

- The text is "**This is a glyph test**"
- Font is java.awt.**Font[family=Dialog,name=sans,style=plain,size=72]** (pt)
- Screen resolution is **96 dpi**
- Platform is **x86-64 Linux X11** with **Java 8**

Screen resolution has programmatically been determined with **Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()** and corresponds with **xdpyinfo**.

The results of **fontMetrics.get...()**, **graphics.drawString()** and **drawGlyphVector()** are all coherent to these IMHO somewhat strange result values:

- Bounds are java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-71.55469,**w=448.0,h=55.875**]
- Font ascent: **45 px**
- Font descent: **12 px**
- Font height: **57 px**

If I change font size from 72 to 192 pt the results are coherently: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-190.8125,**w=1208.0,h=149.0**], ascent: 119, descent: 31, height: **150**. If I change the **font face**, only width changes while height remains unchanged. (This is what I expected.)

I assumed that AWT uses DTP metrics, where 1 pt is **always 1/72 inch**. On a 96 dpi screen, 96 pixels would make up one inch (physically). (The provided screen dpi value does not necessarily reflect values of actual physical equipment accurately, but that doesn't matter here.) Hence, 72 pt == 1 inch should translate to 96. I expected to find something close to **96** somewhere in the resulting size values (or combinations of them), likely the height ones, but none of them seems even close to it...

**Questions**:

- Can anyone reproduce similar values like mine or are they very atypical?
- How are bounds height / font height calculated? (I expected font height to be 96 px with 72 pt)
- Or: what is the interpretation (unit) of the font size parameter in Java, if it is not DTP-like point?
- Is it just rounding or other inaccuracy errors within AWT that make **bounds.h** differ from both **metrics.height** and **metrics.ascent + metrics.descent** or is this difference valuable information?
- Have I missed other relevant parameters? (AffineTransforms are not involved here.)
- Is there a safe (cross-platform) way to make font height reliably 96 px on 96 dpi devices and 72 pt font size? (Would just multiplying font size with a constant value be acceptable?)

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, don't use so much **bold** in your question, it makes it hard to read. Put technical terms between these: `

Comment: That's a lot of questions, so I assume you've seen [this stackoverflow help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that starts by telling you to *first search for the anwers yourself* using web searches etc. Did you find any pages that explain how Java2D deals with font metrics? It seems unlikely that there are none, especially since it's been around for a long time, and the javadocs can be pretty elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: **it was my fault!**

More precisely: I actually initialized the Font object not by simple `new Font (Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 72))` or similar, but by using the `new Font(Map<? extends AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute,?> attributes)` constructor instead. That one got a map with all sorts of font attributes, preset from my config. Because one variable was preset with a wrong value, it effectively included a `map.put (SUPERSCRIPT, SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER);` (not as clear in my actual code as shown here).

So, effectively those strange bounds are the result of the font being created as its smaller **superscript** variant all the time here. Without that, the bounds / created text size come much closer to what I expected:

Dialog,style=plain,size=72], height: 84, ascent: 67, descent: 17, bounds: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-66.83203,w=681.0,h=83.8125]

Though they're not quite exactly the aimed sizes, they're much closer. Thanks to **user1803551** for the MCVE suggestion which brought me on track. For the sake of completeness, here it is (imports omitted):

```
public final class TextRenderTest extends WindowAdapter {

int fontSource;
static private final String TESTTEXT = "This is a glyph test";
static public void  main (String [] args) { new TextRenderTest ().main (); }

void main () {
 Frame frame = new Frame ("Text render test") {
    @Override public void paint (Graphics g) {
     FontMetrics    fm;
     Font           font;
        g.setFont (fontSource++ % 2 == 0 ? createFont () : new Font (Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 72));
        g.drawString (TESTTEXT, 16, 96);
        fm = g.getFontMetrics ();
        System.out.println (
            "DPI: "      + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenResolution () +
            ", font: "   + g.getFont ()    + ", font height: " + fm.getHeight () +
            ", ascent: " + fm.getAscent () + ", descent: "     + fm.getDescent () +
            ", bounds: " + fm.getStringBounds (TESTTEXT, g)); } };
    frame.setBounds (64, 32, 800, 280);
    frame.setVisible (true);
    frame.addWindowListener (this);
}
static private Font createFont () {
 HashMap <TextAttribute,Object> map = new HashMap<TextAttribute,Object> (9, 1.0f);
    map.put (FAMILY, "sans");
    map.put (WEIGHT, 500);
    map.put (WIDTH, 1);
    map.put (SIZE, 72);
    map.put (SUPERSCRIPT, SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER);   // <-- Something like this was the fault
    return new Font (map);
}
@Override public void windowClosing (WindowEvent event) { event.getWindow ().dispose (); }
}
```

This sample demonstrates both variants in a flip-flop manner: expected bounds and unexpected bounds (using superscript). The repaint procedure is dirty, just regard the console output.

So I can answer all my questions:

1. No, others would be very unlikely able to reproduce these strange results  ;-)
2. My expectations were basically correct, though in detail there remain small variations.
3. Interpretation (unit) of font size seems to be basically Point, indeed.
4. Those small variations are the only thing I cannot explain yet, although they're negligible for me.
5. Missed the SUPERSCRIPT parameter
6. Likely no need for further compensations at all any more